# How to access a nested object inside another object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, vue-router

I am using Vue.js an I have a data object that I want to access properties dynamically. But I can't seem to be able to access the properties of the filters object dynamically.

```
export export default {
    template: ``,
    data() {
        return {
            something: 'This is some value.',
            filters: {
                fullSearch: 'This is full search.'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can access "something" but I can't access filters.fullSearch dynamically.

This works

```
console.log(this['something']) // This is some value.
```

But this does not work

```
console.log(this['filters.fullSearch']) // Component.js:589 undefined
```

Here is the full code. I am looping through all of the properties of this.$route.query and assigning them to filters in my data like this. But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.$route.query)) {
    if (this['filters.' + key] !== undefined) {
        this['filters.' + key] = value
    }
}
```

Comment: console.log(this['filters']['fullSearch']) will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
console.log(this['filters']['fullSearch'])
```

or

```
console.log(this['filters'].fullSearch)
```

or

```
console.log(this.filters.fullSearch)
```

Comment: The first one gives a syntax error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: That is because you don't have the `'` (single quote) at the end of your string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to address the inner object with the right [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```
this['filters']['fullSearch']
```

or with static properties

```
this.filters.fullSearch
```

Comment: The first gives - syntax error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: have you tried `this['filters']['fullSearch']`? with the keys as strings in brackets?

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed the dot and bracket notation. The following solution will work.

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.$route.query)) {
    if (this['filters'][key] !== undefined) {
        this['filters'][key] = value
    }
}
```